# Failed to retrieve access token google-app-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying out the [appengine-mapreduce python example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/3.2-Example-Code) and getting into endless waiting for the mapreduce.mapper_pipeline.MapperPipeline task as it retries to retrieve access token.
I run it locally. What could be wrong? Thanks.

```
./build.sh run_demo    
INFO     2016-06-01 14:00:00,296 handlers.py:1381] Processing kickoff for job 1571507958375F58F3135
INFO     2016-06-01 14:00:00,370 client.py:804] Refreshing access_token
INFO     2016-06-01 14:00:03,413 client.py:827] Failed to retrieve access token: {
  "error" : "internal_failure"
}
ERROR    2016-06-01 14:00:03,414 api_server.py:272] Exception while handling service_name: "app_identity_service"
method: "GetAccessToken"
request: "\n7https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control"
request_id: "CblKNzQHze"
```

Comment: The request looks suspicious, it starts with `\n7`

Answer (score 1):

Deleting `~/.config/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json` fixed the problem.

**Reference:**

[GloudStorage bug in GoogleAppEngineLanucher development server](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11690)